# Is there a defined exception similar to ActionController::UnpermittedParameters, for when a Parameter contains an illegal value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an API endpoint with a parameter named `activate_via`. However, `activate_via` is only allowed to receive two values - "email" or "text". I want to raise an error if that parameter receives anything else.

Originally I was thinking to raise ActionController::UnpermittedParameters, however now I realize that the real purpose of that error is when a param KEY that is not permitted is passed, not a VALUE.

Is there an already defined error for this purpose? Or should I just define my own?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `ArgumentError`

```
raise ArgumentError.new("invalid argument for Activate via") unless %w(email text).include?(params['activate_via'])
```